# Nexus nexus-3.9.0-01-win64 Upload NuGet Packages

Tags: nuget, nexus, artifacts

Is there a way i can upload existing nuget packages to nexus at onetime. I am trying to upload close to 200 nuget packages and i am wondering if i can upload all packages at once.

Comment: Have a look here:  https://github.com/DarthHater/nexus-repository-import-scripts

Comment: Great, I currently have all the nuget packages on Windows. I will try to use the same logic to create for Windows. I was looking for an official way of uploading multiple files.

Comment: It should be pretty easy to script, the command needed is just "nuget push somepackage.nuget $APIKEY -Source $REPO_URL".  Alternatively you could use REST API upload, but I think that would be more work.

Comment: Yes I am going to recursively get all the packages inside a particular folder and push them to nexus